# Jelastic log rotation

Tags: logging, jelastic

I use jelastic cloud. And I <del>need</del> have to clear logs manualy.

How can I make log rotation for nodes (especially **apache** and **nginx**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log rotation should be configured and enabled by default on every type of Jelastic node.

If you are seeing issues with this or you want to adjust the log rotation details in some way, I recommend to contact your hosting provider's support team to check it.

Comment: Hosting provider said that I need to add crontab task for logrotate. But there are not cron folder in nginx node.

Comment: @verybadbug I don't think your user (running the cron) will have appropriate permissions for that.

Comment: Checked this further, and by default the cron already exists (in cron.daily). There's also already logrotate.d/nginx config (for example) defined to rotate the log files.

It's surprising that your hosting provider does not know about this!

Comment: Ok.. I'll contact with my provider and ask about this. Thanks.

Comment: Yes.. Provider fully configure log rotation on environment. And later I ask for make changes in rotation (time of execution), that the provider also made. It remains to verify that old logs is removing.

Answer (score 1):

You can to clear logs manually from your dashboard.

[image]

Unfortunately,in Jelastic logrotate configuration and editing is not available for users.

Comment: Yes, I do so. But I need to do this every day, because there are ~2Gb logs per day.